# Syncing with Box for multiple users on one desktop computer

Tags: sync, dropbox, cloud-storage, box.com

My desktop computer runs on Windows 7, with a different account for each family member.  I have had no trouble running dropbox from each computer account.  Each computer account syncs automatically with its corresponding dropbox account in the cloud.  Some family members use an office computer and/or a laptop in addition to using the family desktop.  The automatic syncing feature is important for us.

One family member has been given a department decision, not to allow automatic syncing with dropbox.  The only sync software that is allowed now is Box.  So we want to all make the switch over to Box.

But I read on the Box website that it is not possible to have multiple Box accounts running on one computer.

Has anyone found a way around this?

Several family members have folders they do not wish to share with other family members.  Some of those folders are shared with collaborators.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you should make the switch over to Box. Like you state, Box does not support multiple users on one workstation. I think your one family member should take one for the team. If s/he wants to sync with Dropbox, they can just open their local Box folder and drag the contents to Dropbox.com web site to sync any changes.

Comment: I want to understand your idea.  "Open their local Box folder and drag the contents to Dropbox.com web site to sync any changes."  I'm sorry, I don't get your idea.  Can you explain it step by step?  Is this something to do on the office computer where only automatic syncing with Box is permitted?  Right now, the only workaround we have found is to go to the browser interface with dropbox and click through the file hierarchy, and then download the needed files.  It's painful.

Comment: This answer is primarily opinion based. You can upload and download without a desktop client: https://www.dropbox.com/en/help/4455 My thought is that having one person learn to use Box and Dropbox (web only) is really your only option. Since you can't have multiple Box installs on a desktop, what are your options really?

Comment: I know how to use the browser to upload and download, but it's a pain in the neck.  Can you explain "Open their local Box folder and drag the contents to dropbox"?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind having file duplication, You can use BoxSync and the DropBox sync, leave them both running on your pc. Then use a tool like [Dsynchronize](http://dimio.altervista.org/eng/dsynchronize/dsynchronize.html) to set up rules so that those two sync folders are synched internally on your pc at a set interval (or realtime). You'll essentially have two sync locations for all your files then with 2 services backing them up.

I have my files backed up using this like so:

[Dsynchronize settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lnYz4.png)

If you check the Bidirectional Sync option, it will automatically sync your files to both cloud services no matter which computer you're logged into or if this one family member is only using Box, when they save something at the office it will sync it and save it to their DropBox at home (provided the computer is running).

For added comfort, you can even have Dsynchronize save file versions for you - this way if you accidentally save over something you're working on it will automatically make a set number of synched previous versions of that file and you define how many versions are held :)

Adds a redundancy so that it's very unlikely that you'll ever lose and data and means you don't have to migrate your whole family to another platform.

Comment: Thanks for posting.  I hope this is usefulf or someone else.  For me, it sounds too daunting!  We ended up using OneDrive which the department also allows.  (I don't particularly like it.)

Comment: I hear you - I have another idea...

Answer (score 0):

I didn't want to add this until I confirmed that it could be done, but a simpler solution would be to use Zapier to link the Box and Dropbox accounts. It would avoid the local duplication issues mentioned in my previous solution and is relatively simple to use and free for simple 'zaps' like this.

Worth checking out here: https://zapier.com/zapbook/box/dropbox/